# converting JSON OBJECT to JSON ARRAY

Tags: java, json

This is very simple one but struggeling. help me out of this.

I am having a json data { "abc":"test","bed":"cot","help":"me"}

I want to convert above jsonObject into JSON ARRAY like [{ "abc":"test","bed":"cot","help":"me"}]

```
JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(str.toString());
Iterator x = obj.keys();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

while (x.hasNext()) {
  for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++) {
    LOG.info("=============");
    String key = (String) x.next();
    jsonArray.put(obj.get(key));
  }
}
```

I am getting only values. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add JSONObject to JSONArray java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417911/add-jsonobject-to-jsonarray-java)

Comment: Nope ... it's totally different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly put JsonObject i.e. obj into jsonArray

```
jsonArray.put(obj);
//result is [{ "abc":"test","bed":"cot","help":"me"}]
```

**Final code**

```
JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
//simply put obj into jsonArray
jsonArray.put(obj);
//result is [{ "abc":"test","bed":"cot","help":"me"}]
```

Comment: may i knw the jar name?

Comment: @ArunkumarThangavel These are built-in classes.
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("value");
```

Comment: Ummm ... use a loop?

Comment: Passing string in JSONObject(string) but still getting error . Provided type Map while required type is String.